# spresense Wi-Fiモジュール is110b によるデータの送信について

Tags: spresense, wifi

現在、IDY社製のWi-Fiモジュールを使ってspresenseの無線化を試しています。
Wi-Fi本体の名称は、GM2200Mといいます。
https://qiita.com/Inoue_Minoru/items/d6513670c5988884f0b0
こちらのサイトを参考にやっていますが、
[image: プログラム書き込み後のシリアルモニターの応答]

このような返事しか帰ってきません。またモジュールを外した状態でも同じ応答になります。
node.jsは、Hello Worldをlocalhostで表示できることを確認してから使っています。
テスターで電源は供給されていることが確認できたので、初期不良ではない？と思います。
何かしら分かる方いらっしゃいましたら、回答頂けますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

1点、気になるところがあります。

このボードは、下記のページを見ると、発売時期によってバージョンが異なるようです。
https://idy-design.com/product/is110b.html

自分の手持ちは、V1.0A なので、こちらの記事どおりで動作するのするのですが、
https://qiita.com/Inoue_Minoru/items/d6513670c5988884f0

おそらく、新しく購入されたものの場合、V1.0C などになっているのかと思います。
その場合、GitHub上のリポジトリで使うのではなく、下記のパッチを使うようです。

https://idy-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/0001-Support-iS110B-typeC-module.zip

自分は、V1.0C を持っていないので、確認はできていないのですが、このあたりを試してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、返事遅くなりました。
ありがとうございます。
改めて指摘されたところ調べたところ、タイプCのモジュールでした。
パッチの使い方がよく分からなかったので、タイプC対応版という方でコードの書き換えを行った結果、NuttShell (NSH)　 NuttX-8.2　nsh> [K　、という応答に変化しましたが、これまたどういうことなのか、、、

Comment: パッチの使い方がよく分からないです

Comment: Arduino IDEの環境で、nsh> が出ることが以前あった気がしますが、PCをリブートして再度トライしたら動いたことがありました。ご参考程度ですが…。

Comment: やり直したところ、Is Your module iS110B_TypeA or iS110B_TypeB ?という文が頭にきて、以降は以前の画像のものと同じレスポンスになっています。typecなのにその表示がないのはどういうことでしょう...。.patchファイルの当て方が分かったので、当てましたがリブートしてもこの反応です。

Comment: 書き換えのあったcppファイルのコード調べてみたら、設定がtypeA及びtypeBをデフォルトに動作するようになっていました。typeCで動くように書き換えるとようやくはじめのものとおもわれる動作が表示できるようになりました。しかし途中でSPI: Time outなる別のエラーが出たのでその部分のコードから原因を探っています。

Comment: 少し前にようやく解決しました。どうやら参考のサイトの書き方が問題でした。参考の書き方されるとwindowsのコマンドプロンプトを使用するように読めます。正しくはnode.jsのコマンドプロンプトでサーバーを開きます。初心者なものでその辺の融通聞かないのもあるかもしれませんが。

Comment: あまりお力になれなかったかもしれませんが、うまくいったようで良かったです。

Comment: エラー自体はじめからnode.js のcmdで開いていれば出なかったので、当時は回答していただけただけで気が楽になりました。ありがとうございました。